# How to fill the map when creating a netCDF file with Python Dataset?

Tags: python, grid, dataset, netcdf, point

I have a set of 203 points with their corresponding latitude and longitude in txt files. I would like to obtain a netCDF file with a map with all values in the continent but I obtain a map with each point in each station. I would like to fill in the Spanish continent, although I only have 203 stations, and any method (interpolation, nearest neighbors...) is welcome.

This is a capture of the output map with ncview:
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKdS6.png)

These are the input files:

file_stations file:

https://www.aemet.es/documentos/es/serviciosclimaticos/cambio_climat/datos_diarios/dato_observacional/rejilla_50km/tmax-realtot.zip

geograficas file:

https://www.aemet.es/documentos/es/serviciosclimaticos/cambio_climat/datos_diarios/ayuda/puntos-grid-geograficas.zip

And this is an example of the code:

```
import os; os.environ['HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK']='2'
import argparse
import cf_units
import dask
import datetime
import fnmatch
import glob
import logging
import sys
import time
import unicodedata
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import xarray as xr
from calendar import monthrange
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
from netCDF4 import Dataset,num2date,date2num
from cdo import Cdo

cdo = Cdo()
cdo.debug = True


df_stations = pd.read_csv(file_stations, header = None)
df_geo = pd.read_csv(geograficas, header = None)

# Example for the first line
line = 0

# Extract year, month and day per line
y = '19' + list(filter(str.strip, df_stations[0][line].split(' ')))[3]
m = list(filter(str.strip, df_stations[0][line].split(' ')))[2].zfill(2)
d = list(filter(str.strip, df_stations[0][line].split(' ')))[1].zfill(2)
out_file = "out_" + str(y) + str(m) + str(d) + ".nc"

ncout = nc.Dataset(out_file, 'w', format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')

# Create dimensions
ncout.createDimension('time', None)
lon_arange = np.linspace(-14.148,7.49,203) # widest range 
ncout.createDimension('lon', len(lon_arange))
lat_arange = np.linspace(33.5,46.,203)
ncout.createDimension('lat', len(lat_arange))

# Create variables
lons = ncout.createVariable('lon', 'float32', ('lon',))
lats = ncout.createVariable('lat', 'float32', ('lat',))
time_var = ncout.createVariable('time', 'float32',('time',))
main_var = ncout.createVariable('tasmax', 'float32', ('time','lat','lon'), fill_value = -9999.)

# Fill values
lons[:] = lon_arange
lats[:] = lat_arange
time_unit_out = "hours since 1850-01-01 00:00:00"
date_time = datetime.datetime(int(y), int(m), int(d), 12, 0, 0)
time_var[:] = cf_units.date2num(date_time, time_unit_out, cf_units.CALENDAR_GREGORIAN)
line_date = list(filter(str.strip, df_stations[0][line].split(' ')))

# Go through all latitudes and longitudes of df_geo[0][point] to fill main_var
for point in range(0,203):
    # Some lines are shifted one space to the right
    if df_geo[0][point].split(' ')[1] == '':
        val_lon = df_geo[0][point].split(' ')[2]
        val_lat = df_geo[0][point].split(' ')[4]
    else:
        val_lon = df_geo[0][point].split(' ')[1]
        val_lat = df_geo[0][point].split(' ')[3]

    for ilon in range(0,len_lons):
        for ilat in range(0,len_lats):
              if round(float(val_lon), 1) == round(lon_arange[ilon],1) and round(float(val_lat),1) == round(lat_arange[ilat],1):
                    main_var[0,ilat,ilon] = float(line_date[point+4])/10 + 273.15

ncout.close()
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you very much in advance.

I tried to change the grid to different sizes and expected that the land map was full of values

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please explain things more clearly? It's hard to understand this without downloading the data and running the code. What are you trying to do? You want to fill in a continent? Which continent? You only have 203 stations? How do you want to fill in? Interpolation? Nearest neighbour?

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your answer. I'll edit the description.